# C# WPF 動作時の挙動について

Tags: c#, wpf

C# WPF
初歩的なことで申し訳ないのですが、予め準備してあるデータをループなどで処理しているときにMainWindowが操作不能になるはどうにかできないのでしょうか？
Timerを用いて無限ループを回避しても、一定時間は動くのがとまってしまいます。

何か解決方法、もしくは仕組みについての参考文献等があればお教えいただきたいです。

Comment: 別スレッド化すれば解決できると思いますが

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、最初に理解するべきなのは、この場合マルチスレッド処理が必要ということです。
WPFでは、UI上のボタンが押下された場合など、コードビハインドやコマンドパターンで呼び出されるメソッドはUIスレッドで動作します。UIスレッドは描画に使用されるスレッドですから、そのまま長時間そのメソッド内で処理を行い続けるとUIの描画が止まってしまうのです。

様々な手続きで、長時間メソッド内で処理を継続したい場合、UIスレッドとは別のスレッドで実行する必要があります。マルチスレッド処理に関しては単純にこうすれば解決、という話ではなく非常に複雑な問題が絡み合うので、WPF+マルチスレッドやUIスレッドについていろいろと検索してみてください。

昨今の解決策としては、takemori_kondoさんの挙げているasync/awaitやTaskを利用するのがモダンな手法ですが、古典的なアプローチとしてはBackgroundWorker等を利用したり、よりプリミティブにThreadを自分で生成することもできます。
async/awaitは非常に便利なのですが、マルチスレッドは非常に奥が深くやっかいな問題ですので、まずはプリミティブな手法を色々と試すなどして理解を深められることをお薦めします。

.NET開発における非同期処理の基礎と歴史（1/2） - ＠IT
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/masterasync_01/masterasync_01_01.html
非同期処理の基礎
https://www.slideshare.net/ufcpp/ss-34533225

【WPF】お手軽簡単別スレッド BackgroundWorker | 創造的プログラミングと粘土細工
http://pro.art55.jp/?eid=1180258

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
非同期処理に関して自分でしらべてみることにします。

Answer (score -1):

.NETはUI動作と内部動作を独立させる機能として、async/await（TAP）を利用できます。

・他の言語に比べUI非同期機能がかなり低レベルに実装されているため、
　組み方を間違えるとすぐハングします。作法にのっとって実装する必要があります。
　例えばasync/await（TAP）で並列処理を実装しようとすると、大抵うまくいきません。
　async/await（TAP）はUIとバック処理を分離する目的用と割り切って使った方がいいです。
・作法にのっとって実装していくと、ほぼ全てのメソッドをasync化する必要があるため、
　編集範囲が広大になります。（既存のメソッドにasync修飾子をつけて戻り値も機械的にTaskまたはTaskに置き換えるだけですが）
・asyncメソッドは、ref/out引数が使用できません。
　複数の値を返したい場合は、Tupleなどで書き直す必要があります。

要約

1. asyncしたいメソッドはasync修飾子つけ、Asyncサフィックスをつける
2. awaitでの呼び出しが必要なasyncメソッドは、asyncメソッド内でしか呼び出せない
3. 1, 2より、既存の自作メソッドが全てasyncになっていく。
4. 場合によっては、標準ライブラリもAsync対応版を覚えなおす必要が出てくる。

書き換え自体は非常に単調なので、そんなに難しくはありません。
 1. 呼び出し元から非同期で動作させたいメソッドの戻り値を機械的に次のように書き換える。
　ただし、ref/outを使用している場合は、Tuple等で複数返すように調整する
 void →　Task
 void以外　→　Task
 2. 1のメソッド定義にasync修飾子を追加し、Asyncサフィックスをついたものにリネームする。
 3. 1を呼び出しているメソッド全ても1,2の処理を行う。
 4. 以下、1～3を最初の呼び出し元まで繰り返す